# Upload videos from iOS using html5 without compression

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I'm building a website where I have need of allowing user to capture and upload videos without compressing the videos. Using the following HTML code it works perfectly on Android, but on iOS uploaded files are compressed automatically:

```
  <input type="file" id="videoFile" capture="environment" accept="video/*">
```

Files are not compressed if I include the `multiple` argument and remove the `capture` argument, and users are manually selecting files. However, this is not very convenient for our application.

Does any one know of any workaround of capturing and uploading high-quality video recordings from iOS?

I've tried to include the `multiple` argument, but this doesn't work if the user capture a recording directly. I've also tried having users manually canceling compression of videos while uploading, but this has turned out harder to follow in practice.

Similar questions have been asked before, but I haven't found any good answers.

Comment: Looks like another Apple method to wall its garden.